# How to identify what started a Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I get the name of the class and method within which the current thread was spawned?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364849/can-i-get-the-name-of-the-class-and-method-within-which-the-current-thread-was-sp)

Are there any tools (perhaps a javaagent) that will let me identify what started a thread after the event?

I have a Tomcat that won't shut down, and the thread names (from the dump) aren't of much use.

Comment: Definite duplicate :) voted to close.

Comment: I was going to say it is not duplicate because OP wants to know this after the fact. Then I realized the OP wants to close it:)

Answer (score 0):

The lowest level call of a stack trace might indicate how/why a thread was started...

Answer (score 0):

Do one thing, [print the stack trace](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#printStackTrace%28%29), and you will get who started the thread.

Comment: You don't have to print it. It's available from a getter: [Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getStackTrace()) since 1.5

Comment: Does `tomcat` do something special here? Otherwise, the stacktrace stops at `Thread.run`

Comment: I already have the stack trace (hence my comment saying I had the dump) but that doesn't give any useful information.